# Unix/Linux Redirection and piping

Tags: linux, bash, unix, command-line

i am doing an exercise from the book "your Unix/Linux ultimate guide" trying to best learn the command line, this question i was not able to answer after thinking about it for like 45 minutes and the solution is not given in the book, here is the question:

> Suppose there is an access log file named "access.log" (one entry per line), a filter "userfilter" which only outputs lines in the access log's format corresponding to entries for a user, "roomfilter" which only outputs lines in the access log's format corresponding to entries for a room, and "codefilter" which only outputs lines in the access log's format corresponding to one of either "entry", "exit", or "denied". All of the filters accept one argument to specify the value on which to output. Give a command to display how many times "winston" entered room "101"

any help in the right direction will be appreciated, thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In unix terminology a filter is something that gets lines of text from somewhere, modifies them one by one, and outputs them. In this context, "modify" can also mean eat / discard.

Typically you use a filter by feeding it with data; for example:

```
cat access.log | userfilter fred
```

would launch two commands: "cat access.log" takes a file (access.log), and sends it out. Command "userfilter fred" launch a second process which takes lines of text but only outputs those which match the criteria user=fred. The magic is done by the pipe symbol |, which launches two commands and connects the output of the first to the input of the second.

"cat", if not told differently, output data to the console (well, really is "standard output").
"userfilter" is not different - if not told differently, sends data to standard output. Actually, all these commands ("filters") will *always* send data to standard output (it's the unix way): it is the shell that manipulates the pipes and connects them. But I wanted to add "if not told differently" because there are commands that can be told to behave differently.

Now, you can take the output of the last command and send it elsewhere, guess how? By adding more and more pipes "|".

I suppose you would start your command line like this:

```
cat access.log | userfilter winston | roomfilter 101
```

In the command above, all all the lines from access.log go through the userfilter, which only outputs those with user winston in them. In turn, these resulting lines go to roomfilter, which only outputs those with room 101. The result is that all activity of winston in room 101 is output.

I leave to you the last filter step, but I will help you about counting the results.

Supposing you are no more interested in the final (relevant) log lines, but in counting them, there is a nice "standard" filter in unix to do exactly that: count (it can count lines, characters, words). Its name is "wc" or, in common unix speaking, `wc(1)`. That "1" means it is a normal command, and you can read explanations (manual) about it with the command `man wc`. Nice, isn't it? Besides, wc does not mean water closet - it means "word count".

To count how many lines of text are presented to it, the right syntax is "wc -l". So you can count how many lines are in the file access.log using this command:

```
cat access.log | wc -l
```

If you want to count how many times winston did something, you use:

```
cat access.log | userfilter winston | wc -l
```

I did not give you the full answer, just several bricks to build it by yourself; I hope it is enough - good luck!

Comment: thank you for this detailed explanation it really helped

Answer (score -1):

```
cat access.log | userfilter winston | wc -l >> file.name
```

you can pipe the outcome in to a new file.